# Displaying list item targets below the top of the screen

Tags: html, css

I've got a lot of list items that are targets, i.e. they have an id – e.g. **li id="sub0098"**

Because I've got a navigation menu at the top of small devices, I've used the following css code to ensure the target displays 55px below the top of the screen & so it does not get covered by the menu.

```
/* Offset targets due to top nav bar */

:target::before {

  content: "";

  display: block;

  height: 55px;

  margin-top: -55px;

}
```

(NB: I didn't use padding (or margins) instead of the above, as 55px between list items is far too big.)

**My problem is** that when I activate a link to a list item on iOS, iOS puts the 55px (or 5px) space in immediately before the text entered for the list item and after the list item's letter (or number or symbol). i.e. the list item's number appears higher up. e.g.:

> **A.**
>
> **___First thing on list blah blah**

("___" is to imply indent.)

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Comment: Maybe add a link to a codepen page with your probem?

Comment: Thanks Sujan. I used a work-around, as per the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I used a work-around. I inserted "target" blank list items with the target id, before each list item I have links to. For these extra list items that hold the target id, I used visibility: hidden & other settings so that they’re not seen.